# Trying to log in to JIRA in Docker container and getting SSL: WRONG_SIGNATURE_TYPE error

Tags: docker, ssl, python-requests, jira, jira-rest-api

I'm new to Docker and I'm not very experienced in SSL/certificates etc.

I'm working on a web application that lets the user log in to JIRA via JIRA API to do things. This works on my computer and I don't get any SSL errors. However, when I run it in a Docker container I get
`ssl.SSLError: [SSL: WRONG_SIGNATURE_TYPE] wrong signature type` error.

My friend ran the exact same Dockerfile in his computer and created a container and it works which is confusing.

I checked the `requests` library version on my computer and compared it to the one in Docker container but they are the same. What could be the problem? Thank you

Note: I use Windows

Answer (score 0):

Faced similar problem.
Find the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58268626/ssl-unsupported-protocol-python-3-in-docker)
Just to sum up:

1. There is missing dependencies inside container which your own system already has. You should install them inside docker.
2. Idk how but pyopenssl library should be install to

So, you need to add:

```
RUN    apt-get update \
&& apt-get install openssl \
&& apt-get install ca-certificates
```

In your Dockerfile

And add:

```
pyopenssl==19.1.0
```

To your requirements.txt

If you don't use requirements.txt just add:

```
RUN pip install pyopenssl
```

To your Dockerfile

Hope it'll help

Answer (score 0):

Similar issue happened to me - python tls requests were working fine on my host, but failed with `WRONG_SIGNATURE_TYPE` once I dockerized my script.

The issue seems to stem from where requests lib uses [older TLS stacks with OpenSSL 1.1.1pre9](https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/4775).

I noticed rolling back to `python:3.5.3` stopped the error, however for compatibility with newer versions the [solution posted in github issue thread](https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/4775#issuecomment-478198879) worked fine.

i.e. import the `TLSAdapter`, use it to setup a requests session, then start making requests.