# SSL UNSUPPORTED_PROTOCOL Python 3 in Docker

Tags: python-3.x, docker, ssl

I try to get data from the website via https and got the error with SSL certificate, but when I run on my mac - all works fine.

I also try with curl and got the same error,

```
curl: (35) error:1425F102:SSL routines:ssl_choose_client_version:unsupported protocol
```

I run the parser in Docker container 
My Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.7

WORKDIR /parser
COPY ./requirements.txt .

RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . /parser
```

I get the error below:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                                                                                       │
│     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 672, in urlopen                                                                                                                                          │
│       chunked=chunked,                                                                                                                                                                                                                     │
│     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 376, in _make_request                                                                                                                                    │
│       self._validate_conn(conn)                                                                                                                                                                                                            │
│     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 994, in _validate_conn                                                                                                                                   │
│       conn.connect()                                                                                                                                                                                                                       │
│     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 394, in connect                                                                                                                                              │
│       ssl_context=context,                                                                                                                                                                                                                 │
│     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 370, in ssl_wrap_socket                                                                                                                                       │
│       return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)                                                                                                                                                                    │
│     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 423, in wrap_socket                                                                                                                                                                       │
│       session=session                                                                                                                                                                                                                      │
│     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 870, in _create                                                                                                                                                                           │
│       self.do_handshake()                                                                                                                                                                                                                  │
│     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 1139, in do_handshake                                                                                                                                                                     │
│       self._sslobj.do_handshake()                                                                                                                                                                                                          │
│   ssl.SSLError: [SSL: UNSUPPORTED_PROTOCOL] unsupported protocol (_ssl.c:1076)                                                                                                                                                             │
│   During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:                                                                                                                                                                      │
│   Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                                                                                       │
│     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send                                                                                                                                                  │
│       timeout=timeout                                                                                                                                                                                                                      │
│     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 720, in urlopen                                                                                                                                          │
│       method, url, error=e, _pool=self, _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2]                                                                                                                                                                      │
│     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 436, in increment                                                                                                                                            │
│       raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))                                                                                                                                                                       │
│   urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='life.pravda.com.ua', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /health/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: UNSUPPORTED_PROTOCOL] unsupported protocol (_ssl.c:1076)'))   │
│   )
```

Comment: upgrade your openssl package

Comment: @LinPy I tried to upgrade OpenSSL package but its doesn`t work

Comment: it seems your website supply unsporrted cert for python, not really sure. tls1 or tls3 ?

Comment: @LinPy No, its problem with docker, when I run on my machine, it`s work fine.

Comment: are you using the same python version ?

Comment: @LinPy, yes Python3.7

Comment: This is not the cause, but I think the folks in this thread are pursuing the same thing: https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/issues/817

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I resolved my problem with following commands in Dockerfile:

```
RUN    apt-get update \
    && apt-get install openssl \
    && apt-get install ca-certificates
```

And also need to add python package `pyopenssl` in `requirements.txt`

Comment: didn't work for me, though installed the specified packages

Comment: not solved after installing pyopenssl using python:3.6.10-buster docker image.

Comment: This solution didn't work for me, also you need to import SSL in python using: 
`from OpenSSL import SSL`, for the original solution (posted here) to work.

Comment: this did not work in python:3.6.12-buster docker image. Also tried `from OpenSSL import SSL` but did not work.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure it's not about Docker or certificate but you're need to check which of protocols that server could talk, like this:

```
nmap --script ssl-enum-ciphers -p 443 this-is-your-site.com
```

then setup SSL context that should works in your case:

```
import ssl
ssl_context = ssl.create_default_context()
# Sets up old and insecure TLSv1.
ssl_context.options &= ~ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1_3 & ~ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1_2 & ~ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1_1
ssl_context.minimum_version = ssl.TLSVersion.TLSv1
```

and use custom HTTPAdapter for this mountpoint this-is-your-site.com.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue on `Python 3.8.1`, but not `Python 3.7.4` using `mysql-connector-python`. Then switching to `pymysql` resolved it. Just a heads up for future readers.

Comment: I experienced this issue when upgrading from ubuntu:18.04 and ubuntu:20.04, caused by switching from Python 3.6 to Python 3.8.  I fixed by sticking with 3.6, but will likely resolve by switching libraries when we do upgrade.

Comment: facing same issue after upgrade to py 3.8 from 3.6. any idea what is the root cause?